# "L" machine size for Decision Optimization in Watson Machine Learning

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I am using [watson-machine-learning-client-V4](https://pypi.org/project/watson-machine-learning-client-V4/) (Python 3.7) to access [Decision Optimization (DO) in IBM Watson Machine Learning (WML)](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/blog/announcements/decision-optimization-now-available-in-watson-machine-learning-service). I am using runtime do_12.9 and type do-cplex_12.9. I am able to create deployments and solve my models using an "S" size machine (2 vCPU and 8 GB RAM) and "M" size machine (4 vCPU and 16 GB RAM). According to the service specifications, an "L" size machine (16 vCPU and 64 GB RAM) should also be available for DO. However, I get the following error when trying to use an "L" machine (for the exact same model that deploys and solves fine in "S" and "M") stating that compute name "L" is not allowed:

```
watson_machine_learning_client.wml_client_error - WARNING - Deployment creation failed. Error: 400. {"trace":"6f170e3971bfaec481aee73d1761cc40","errors":[{"code":"deployment_type_undefined","message":"Compute name L not allowed for DO runtime.Allowed values 'List(S, M, XL)'","target":{"type":"Json","name":"payload.compute.name"}}]}
```

Per the message above stating that "XL" size is allowed for DO, I also attempted to run my model on an "XL" machine, but got the following error after deployment creation with the job status:

```
'errors': [{'code': 'error_in_instance_creation', 'message': 'Instance creation of t-shirt-size XL and type do12.9 failed.'}]}}
```

Shouldn't "L" machines be available for DO on WML?

Answer (score 0):

Decision Optimization has a subset of machines available, specified in [hardware specs documentation](https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/wsj/analyze-data/ml-hardware-configs.html). Size `L` was only introduced in 2022 and `XS` and `ML` are still not available for Decision Optimization (though can be used for other services).